# core file deleted in woocommerce / wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plesk

I have noticed that the file "wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php" is deleted automatically in production. Even if I upload this file via ftp, it gets deleted after some time ( ~5min ).

I cannot reproduce this behaviour in the local environment.Do you know any way to discover who deletes this file?

Wordpress: 5.6
Woocommerce: 4.8
Production environment is hosted in plesk 18.0.30

Comment: As wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php is quite common vector for Wordpress' security vulnerabilities [1](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-9787/), then maybe it's your webhost who checks for it's existence and deletes it? I would ask it from them, just in case.

Comment: Did you double checked whether there's any kind of malware or something already present in the file that you are uploading? I mean some some hosting providers have their firewalls setup in such a way that it would probably delete the file if they find anything suspicious

Comment: The file is exactly the same as the original, which can be found here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact same issue here. Took me a while to figure it out. The file is constantly being deleted. It causes a whole mess on the admin panel (images not loading, themes or plugins cannot be installed, theme settings cannot be modified, etc.). I discovered it's some kind of a scheduled job on the server that deletes all instances of the file (even if you backed it up on another folder) and it is not related with WP Toolkit security optimizations. Ι've already sent a message on my hosting provider and will post an answer once it is resolved.

EDIT: Turns out it was a misconfigured antivirus that was deleting the file from all installations. It was an isolated insident that was solved.